# Find contents between square brackets and quotations

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

So to put it straight, lets say I have this string:

`command [stuff] [stuff [inside] this] "string" "another [thing] string"`

Inside of my code I want to grab all the things with quotation marks and put them in an array and grab all the things inside of outer most brackets (everything inside of the outside brackets) and put them in their own array. Like so:

```js
const string = `command [stuff] [stuff [inside] this] "string" "another [thing] string"`;

let quotations = ["string", "another [thing] string"]
let brackets = ["stuff", "stuff [inside] this"] // I do not want to include any brackets found inside of quotation marks
```

I have tried to make a regex that would do this, but I am just having a lot of trouble understanding how I would set it up. I did find these two regex which find the stuff in quotations and brackets but they aren't 100% what I am looking for:

```js
// JavaScript Regex
const regexStrings = /(["'])(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?\1/g;
const regexBrackets = /\[(.*?)\]/g;
```

Comment: so is `thing` not in the brackets array because it's within quotes?

Comment: @Jamiec yes, quotes are basically highest parent

Comment: It seems you foresee backslashes as escape characters, but they don't appear in the example input. Are such backslashes functioning as escapes between quotes only, or anywhere in the input string, so they could also escape square brackets, for instance, so they wouldn't count for the search of bracket pairs.

Comment: What should happen when a quoted string appears within square brackets? Does it still go to the `quotations`? What then happens with the pair of brackets?

Comment: Note that it's not possible to match an unknow level of nested brackets with javascript regex.

Comment: This type of problem is much easier to solve with a tokenizer than with a regex.

Comment: @trincot So those are good questions. Answer to the first one, think of the quotes as if I am finding a string in code, so when you see \" it means that it is apart of the text and is not an ending quotation mark. Then answer to the second question is brackets can contain quotes but those quotes will appear in both the brackets array and quotations array. Brackets would just include everything in between the start and end too

Comment: Ok for the second answer, but my first question is not answered: does this escaping behaviour also apply *outside* of the quotation mark pairs such that it can affect how square brackets are interpreted?

Comment: @trincot I should only apply when *inside* quotation marks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no support for recursion in JavaScript's regex syntax, so you'll need to throw in some code in order to cope with an arbitrary depth of bracket nesting.

I would therefore go for splitting the string into:

- quotations (starting and ending with an quotation mark, taking into account backslash escaping)
- A substring that does not have any of `'"[]` characters
- A single `[` or `]`

Then use a depth counter to keep track how deeply the brackets are so you know when to build a bracket substring by concatenating the tokens along the way.

Here is a snippet, using a bit more complex input string than you provided:

```js
function solve(str) {
    let tokens = str.match(/(['"])((\\.|.)*?)\1|[^[\]'"]+|./g);
    let brackets = [];
    let quotations = [];
    let bracket = "";
    let depth = 0;
    for (let token of tokens) {
        if (token[0] === '"' || token[0] === "'") {
            quotations.push(token.slice(1, -1));
        } else if (token === "[") {
            depth++;
        } else if (token === "]") {
            depth--;
            if (depth < 0) throw "Unbalanced brackets";
            if (!depth) {
                brackets.push(bracket.slice(1));
                bracket = "";
            }
        }
        if (depth) bracket += token;
    }
    if (depth) throw "Unbalanced brackets";
    return {quotations, brackets};
}


const string = String.raw`command [stuff] [stuff [inside [very inside with "escaped \" bracket:]" ]] this] "string" "another [thing] string"`;

console.log(solve(string));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an attempt.

The regex for the quotes will try to find non-quotes between quotes.

The regex for the brackets will first try to match non-quotes between quotes, and then the stuff between brackets.
Then filters out the matches that start with a quote.

There's no recursion, so it's only 1 level of optional brackets within brackets.

```js
const string = `command [stuff] [stuff [inside] this] "string" "another [thing] string"`;

// JavaScript Regex
const regexStrings = /"[^"]*"|'[^']'/g;
const regexBrackets = /"[^"]*"|'[^']'|(\[[^\[\]]*(?:\[[^\[\]]*\])?[^\[\]]*\])/g;

let quotations = string.match(regexStrings)
                       .map(x=>x.replace(/^["']|["']$/g,''));
let brackets = string.match(regexBrackets).filter(x=>!/^["']/.test(x));

console.log(quotations);
console.log(brackets);
```

To get the multilevel nested brackets, here's an extra tokenizer.

```js
function getQuotesAndBrackets(str) {
 const re = /(["'])(?:\\.|.)*?\1|[\[\]]|[^"'\[\]]+/g;
 let quoted = []; let bracketed = [];
 let token = ''; let cnt = 0; let m;
 let nest = "";
 while(m = re.exec(str)) {
   token = m[0][0];
   if(cnt==0 && /["']/.test(token)) { quoted.push(m[0]) }
   else if(token === '[') { nest += token; cnt += 1 }
   else if(token === ']') { nest += token;
     if(cnt > 1) { cnt -= 1 }
     else { bracketed.push(nest); nest = ""; cnt = 0 }
   }
   else if(cnt > 0) { nest += m[0] }
 }
 return {"quotes":quoted, "brackets":bracketed};
} 

// TEST
const string = `all "the [quoted]" [ stuff [inside ["this"] [bracketed] ] ] "thing" [['blah']]`; 
let quotes_and_brackets = getQuotesAndBrackets(string);

console.log(quotes_and_brackets);
```

Comment: Do you know of a way to add a bit of recursion? (This can be done without regex if needed)

Comment: This is not going to work with arbitrary nesting of brackets, also it will treat brackets that occur inside quotations (which should be ignored) which can lead to wrong results. Example input: `["]" hello]`. The "hello" should be inside the bracket, but it is not found.

Comment: @KillerCube Been looking for it, but the regex in javascript is just too minimal. So recursion is done via javascript tricks.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the given string is as follows.

```
'command [stuff] [stuff [inside] this] "string" "another [thing] string"'
          bbbbb   bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb   dddddd   dddddddddddddddddddddd
```

We wish to extract the values marked `bbb...` (within brackets) to one array and values marked `ddd...` (within double-quotes) to a second array.  This can be done in two steps.

**Step 1: extract all strings within double-quotes and replace those matches, including the surrounding double-quotes, with empty strings**

Replace matches of the following regular expression (with the `g` flag set) with empty strings.<sup>1</sup>

```
"([^"]*)"
```

That will return

```
'command [stuff] [stuff [inside] this]  '
          bbbbb   bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
```

which we will use in the second step, as shown below.

As well, the contents of capture group 1 will be `'string'` and `'another [thing] string'`, which we must save.

[Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/eICh7H/1)

This expression reads, "match a double-quote followed by zero or more characters other than a double-quote, followed by a double-quote, with the sting bounded by the double-quotes saved to capture group 1".

**Step 2: extract all strings delimited with brackets that are not within a string that is delimited with brackets**

We can obtain the strings of interest (`'stuff'` and `'stuff [inside] this'`) by matching the regular expression

```
(?<=\[)[^\[\]]*(?:\[[^\[\]]*\])?[^\[\]]*(?=\])
```

[Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/WNlkYP/1)

This expression can be broken down as follows.

```
(?<=\[)     # positive lookbehind asserts match is preceded by '['
[^\[\]]*    # match 0+ chars other than '[' and ']'
(?:         # begin non-capture group
  \[        # match '['
  [^\[\]]*  # match 0+ chars other than '[' and ']'
  \]        # match ']'
)?          # end non-capture group and make it optional
[^\[\]]*    # match 0+ chars other than '[' and ']'
(?=\])      # positive lookahead asserts match is followed by ']'
```

Note that this expression does not work with more than one level of nesting, such as

```
'[stuff [inside [stuff] like] this]'
  bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
```

The regular expression I've given could be modified to handle up to any given number of levels of nesting by extending the approach I have taken, but it becomes unwieldy for more than three levels of nesting.

<sup>1. Alternatively, we could write `"(.*?)"`. Making `.*` lazy (`?`) prevents the match from gobbling up characters, including double-quotes, until the last double-quote in the string is reached. If we were to use `".*"` (a *greedy* match) we would obtain the single match, `'"string" "another [thing] string'"`.</sup>